# Copy a worksheet (data+style) from a workbook to another in Python using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, worksheet

I have a large amount of XLS files (more than 500), and I need to replace in all just the first sheet. Needs to be a perfect copy of data+style (font, background, borders, cell alignment and even images) of the 1st worksheet.

All the solutions that I found in Python using openpyxl only allow it to copy data, without the style. And using xlwings it's not an option because the Linux target machine doesn't have MS Office.

```
import openpyxl as pyxl
import re

basereportworkbook = pyxl.load_workbook(filename="base_template.xlsx")
testreportworkbook = pyxl.load_workbook(filename="file1_to_correct.xlsx")

sheetbase = basereportworkbook.get_sheet_by_name("Coverpage")
sheetreport = basereportworkbook.get_sheet_by_name("Coverpage")

# Remove the 1st page from the file to correct
testreportworkbook.remove(testreportworkbook["Coverpage"])
testreportworkbook.create_sheet("Coverpage")
sheetreport = testreportworkbook.get_sheet_by_name("Coverpage")


# Copying the cell values from template excel file to destination excel file, one by one
mr = sheetbase.max_row 
mc = sheetbase.max_column 

for i in range (1, mr + 1): 
    for j in range (1, mc + 1): 
        # reading cell value from source excel file 
        c = sheetbase.cell(row = i, column = j) 
  
        # writing the read value to destination excel file 
        sheetreport.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value 

# Save the XLS file in the disk
testreportworkbook.save(filename="output.xlsx")
```

This is my code so far, it works just to copy data without formatting style.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `c.value`, you specify that you only want to copy the value and not any other cell attributes (the formatting, etc).
You could use `copy` to move all `_style` formatting over, eg:

```
from copy import copy

sheetreport.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
if cell.has_style:
    sheetreport.cell(row = i, column = j)._style = copy(c._style)
```

...*et cetera*.

However, if you want to just copy the entire worksheet, I would probably just copy the entire workbook and then delete all the other worksheets, rather than iterate over every cell.

```
shutil.copyfile('base_template.xlsx', 'file1_to_correct.xlsx')
testreportworkbook = pyxl.load_workbook(filename='file1_to_correct.xlsx')

for ws in testreportworkbook.worksheets[1:]:
    testreportworkbook.remove_sheet(ws)
```

Also note, from the docs: "You also cannot copy worksheets between workbooks. You cannot copy a worksheet if the workbook is open in read-only or write-only mode."

Comment: 1) I'm going to try this approach to copy the style, from one workbook to another.

2) About delete the worksheet didn't solve my problem, because these other 500 XLS files have multiple worksheets that I need to keep, and just the 1st worksheet in these files needs to be replaced.
That way I will have 2 XLS files: one with the 1st worksheet ("Coverpage"), and another file with the remaining worksheets, and it's not what I pretend.

Comment: I guess if you're okay not to use openpyxl (maybe I took your mention of that too literally), this is something that can be done with win32com.client, copying the entire worksheet between workbooks. The question isn't the same, but I show a version of this in an answer I just posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584460/11846457

Comment: Use "openpyxl" it would be preferable, or another library where I can use in a Linux environment.
Unfortunately, "win32com.client" will not work in this environment.