# Excel crashes after append

Tags: openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to automatically append data. My excel file has picture widgets(Text box) like shown below (highlighted). But the picture widgets are deleted after append. Also, I get the error: "Removed Feature: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)", "Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing3.xml part.  (Drawing shape)". Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this.

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Openpyxl can't read images directly (documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html). There are some types of image it won't save at all.

> Warning:
> openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name.

However, there are some nice solutions on this old post, even though openpyxl functionality has changed since then. Particularly, installing Pillow *via* pip may help you: [Images dissapear in excel documents when copying them with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606139/images-dissapear-in-excel-documents-when-copying-them-with-python)

The alternative is to use libraries other than openpyxl. I have previously had cause to use openpyxl for some functions, and then stitch final image-containing documents together with win32com on Windows, for example.

Comment: I saw your answer for similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563297/openpyxl-corrupts-xlsx-on-save-even-when-no-changes-were-made Does this answer applicable for my question?

Comment: Yes, it well might! That's how I've been doing things. Will only work on Windows.

Comment: In my case I have an excel with multiple sheets with only charts and text boxes.. But, `imageworksheets = [ws if ws.title.endswith('Results') else '' for ws in wb.worksheets]` is not reading the sheets with unsupported images.. And also when i try to open 'outputtemp' excel it says 'Excel found unreadable content..'.. Can you please let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: The unreadable content will be leftovers from the images it's removed. Do you have specific names for your worksheets that you could use, or perhaps something like a value in a specific cell, to indicate which do and don't contain images? My worksheets literally did end with the word "Results"!

Comment: My workbook has 10 worksheets with different names.. 6 worksheets have images and charts.. In the code I have replaced 'Results' with my worksheet names.. I am getting error here: `wb1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), outputtemp))`. The error messgae: "wb1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), outputtemp))
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 8, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)". I am not able to debug this issue..

Comment: Have you already saved the unsupported worksheets as outputtemp? If it can't find that file, it will fail. Original code created a new wb with all the unsupported worksheets, then did `wb.save(outputtemp)`

Comment: The issue resolved by using `del wb[ws]` instaed of `wb.remove(ws)`. But the outputfile output.xlsx created duplicate sheets in excel workbook.. after stitching files together.. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing it all. I guess you need to make sure you are using `del` for every single worksheet that needs to be removed? Have a look at outputtemp as well, to check you're not accidentally putting any extras in there.

Comment: I think the error is in imageoutput "output2" excel. I thought output2 file will have only unsupported images but it has all the excel sheets(like original excel).. I have not made any changes to below code: ` for i, ws in enumerate(imageworksheets[::-1]):
        if not ws:
            wsindex = len(imageworksheets) - i
            imagewb.Worksheets(wsindex).Delete()
imagefileupdated = False ` Should I make any changes here?

Comment: Yes - this code makes two workbooks, "outputtemp", which contains worksheets compatible with openpyxl, and "imageoutput"/"output2", which should contain everything that isn't. They're then stitched together.

Comment: Yes, I understood. But the "imageoutput"/"output2" contains all the excel sheets including openpyxl compatible and non-compatible items.. thats why while joining both excels duplicate sheets are getting created..

Comment: Sure. I guess you will have to remove them somehow, as above with the wb.remove() or the del wb[ws] commands.

Comment: In my code `imageworksheets = [ws if ws.title.endswith('Cases') else '' for ws in wb.worksheets]` I have given 'Cases' instead of 'Results'. 'Cases' has unsupported images. But code is not reading sheetnames and if I use `imageworksheets = [ws if wb['Cases'] else '' for ws in wb.worksheets]` then all the sheets compatible with openpyxl are being returned.. I mean imageworksheets contains all openpyxl supported images.. The list contains only 10 items everytime.. I am not understanding this behavior. <can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: I think you might have to ask this as a new SO question! It's hard to tell what's happening without seeing your workbook structure. You just need to delete every ws that isn't appropriate for each file, however you wish to do that. I'm not claiming it's an elegant solution, but it does work.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you. I have a doubt here: As "imageoutput"/"output2" contains unsupported charts or images and originally these charts are created by referencing to other excel sheets. So once these temporary output2 file is created, the references to other excel sheets are deleted. But while stitching the files, references are not formed again. Can you please help me understand this?

Comment: I see - this might be because of your packages opening the files. For example, openpyxl has "data_only" mode where you can deal with the actual values shown to the user, or you can turn that off and deal with the formulae (but not the actual values). I suspect it's related to that. See if you can find out at which point it's happening - if in openpyxl it could just be a case of using the argument 'data_only = False' when loading the workbook; I'm unsure how to do this at the moment in win32com.